# Bulk Pre-Caching using MyBatis

Tags: java, caching, mybatis

I am using version 3.2.7 of MyBatis and what I want to do is be able to pre-fill the cache before the application is used, so on start-up.

So say in the actual application, I want to search for a specific users info:

```
<select id="selectSpecificUser" parameterType="int">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    users
        WHERE userid=#{id}
    </select>
```

So when this is called, it will check the cache, if it's not there, then it will search the DB.  Is there a way to pre-load this cache with every record from this table so that when this method is called, it picks it up from cache rather than the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following tag to your *SQL Mapping file*:

```
<cache/>
```

That will enable *global caching* in *Mybatis*, and should by default cache all results from `SELECT` statements in the mapper file (subject to a variety of conditions, including *LRU eviction*).

You could warm the cache yourself (as opposed to waiting for the first user-induced invocation) by manually calling that `SELECT` statement in the *setup* (or equivalent) method in your program which is loading the *mapper file*.

[Mybatis Caching Info](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache)

There is also information in that link to change the default behavior, including the type, size, and flush interval; as well as to create a custom cache if your needs are very specific.